# Showing a default Distinct ID in Mixpanel instead of Mixpanel's own arbitrary choice

Tags: mixpanel

In Mixpanel, Users can have multiple Distinct IDs that can be merged under 1 identity. The User is identified with a default Distinct ID, which we’ve noticed is the first one created, not the most recent or one that we would explicitly prefer as the default.

**Is it possible to set a default/primary Distinct ID?**

Also related, once a user signs up, we are using email address as the Distinct ID. If the user changes their email address, would we need to create an alias (we have Identity Merge enabled, FYI), or update the Distinct ID with their new email?

[image]

I did read on this support article titled "[Moving to Identity Merge](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039133851-Moving-to-Identity-Merge)" that:

> **You can no longer control the canonical id for users in Mixpanel**
> The ID merge system will now determine which distinct_id is used as the canonical id for a user in Mixpanel. Any merged id can be used to query for information about a user with our APIs, but the results of the query may return a with different canonical distinct_id value than the one used in the query.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, we use a server-side implementation but this should apply to client side as well, my flow was:

1. send some anonymous `track()` events with `anon_id` & `distinct_id` uuidv4. Let's say the `anon_id` is: `abc-123`
2. authenticate user (now we have access to user_id)
3. call `identify()` with `user_id` and `anon_id`
4. send some track() events with our internal `user_id` as the `distinct_id`. For example the `user_id` is: `1001`

We noticed that the default mixpanel canonical `distinct_id` would always be `abc-123`, not `1001` like we wanted.

After playing around with the mixpanel API I have discovered that if you create the user profile before identifying, the problem seems to be fixed.

```
mixpanel.people.set(distinct_id, props);
mixpanel.identify(); // our api is identify(user_id, anon_id)
```

Going through he flow again, the canonical `distinct_id` is now `1001` instead of `abc-123`. I believe this fixes it because creating a profile for the user sets the canonical `distinct_id` (no source on this though).

To be clear, the flow afterwards is:

1. send some anonymous track() events with `anon_id` & `distinct_id` uuidv4: `abc-123`
2. authenticate user
3. call `mixpanel.people.set(distinct_id, props)` // distinct_id = user_id
4. call `identify()` with `user_id` and `anon_id`
5. send some track() events with our internal user_id: `1001`

Then `1001` should be the default canonical distinct_id instead of `abc-123`.